# ionic build gives error: Function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When doing an `ionic build` for an ionic 2 RC0 project I get the following error:

```
[13:26:17]  ngc: Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/.tmp/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/.tmp/app/app.module.ts
at simplifyInContext (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/static_reflector.js:469:23)
at StaticReflector.simplify (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/static_reflector.js:472:22)
at StaticReflector.annotations (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/static_reflector.js:61:36)
at _loop_1 (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:53:54)
at CodeGenerator.readFileMetadata (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:66:13)
at /Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:100:74
at Array.map (native)
at CodeGenerator.codegen (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:100:35)
at codegen (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js:7:81)
at Object.main (/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-App3/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:30:16)
```

Anyone know what I need to do to get rid of this error?

My app.modules.ts file looks like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';
import { Http, XSRFStrategy, CookieXSRFStrategy  } from '@angular/http';
import { Storage  } from '@ionic/storage';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { PhotoPage } from '../pages/photo/photo';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { GalleryPage } from '../pages/gallery/gallery';
import { SubmittedPage } from '../pages/submitted/submitted';
import { PhotoPage } from '../pages/photo/photo';
import { ResetPasswordPage } from '../pages/reset-password/reset-password';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages/signup/signup';
import { DjangoAuth } from '../providers/djangoAuth';
import { ImageData } from '../providers/imageData';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage,
    PhotoPage,
    GalleryPage,
    SubmittedPage,
    ResetPasswordPage,
    SignupPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, [
      Http,
      DjangoAuth,
      ImageData,
      FormsModule,
      {provide:XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('csrftoken', 'X-CSRFToken')}])
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage,
    PhotoPage,
    GalleryPage,
    SubmittedPage,
    ResetPasswordPage,
    SignupPage
  ],
  providers: [
    DjangoAuth,
    ImageData,
    Storage,
    Camera
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You should remove components one by one to find the problem. Once you have the problem isolated it would be easier to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the call inside imports of :

> {provide:XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('csrftoken',
>   'X-CSRFToken')}

and move to declare factoryFunction

```
export function CookieXSRFStrategyFactory(http:Http) {
return  new CookieXSRFStrategy('csrftoken', 'X-CSRFToken');
```

}

and in your provide write this :

```
provide:XSRFStrategy, useValue: CookieXSRFStrategyFactory
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to help anyone who came here later on. After I upgraded Angular, I came across a similar issue when [`CookieXSRFStrategy()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/CookieXSRFStrategy-class.html) was called directly from the provider.

The above answer didn't work out for me in Angular v2.4.7, but the following did. Note the use of [`useFactory`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#usefactory) to reference the object.

```
import { XSRFStrategy, CookieXSRFStrategy } from '@angular/http';

export function CookieXSRFStrategyFactory() {
  return new CookieXSRFStrategy('csrftoken', 'X-CSRFToken');
}

export const AppCSRF = {
  provide: XSRFStrategy,
  useFactory: CookieXSRFStrategyFactory,
};
```

Then, list `AppCSRF` with the rest of your module's providers.

```
providers: [
  ...
  AppCSRF,
  ...
],
```